# Creating a bitmapfont from images?

Tags: libgdx, fonts, texture-atlas

A bitmapfont consists of a image and a textfile that hold the position and size of each character on that image. Is there any way to create the text file with just a image? Or do I have to manually create the "atlas" for each character, which is kinda tedious.

Here is a line for a character in such a textfile `.fnt`

```
char id=36   x=0     y=0     width=46     height=83     xoffset=1     yoffset=0    xadvance=51     page=0  chnl=0
```

I think `xadvance` would mean how many pixels to advance on the line to put the next character. I have 36 characters `A-Z0-9` but I want upper and lower case to output the same image.

I need this specifically for libgdx but this would probably be the same for any tool that uses a `BitmapFont`.

In addition I have a `xml` file that came with the sheet that includes the characters allong with the other images.

```
<TextureAtlas imagePath="sheet.png">
  ...
  <SubTexture name="letterA.png" x="412" y="835" width="61" height="64"/>
  <SubTexture name="letterB.png" x="460" y="977" width="52" height="66"/>
  <SubTexture name="letterC.png" x="432" y="1613" width="54" height="66"/>
  ...
</TextureAtlas>
```

I also have a each character separately in `PNG` and `Vector`.

To make clear to what I need this is a complete `.fnt` it needs to be accompanied by a single image that holds all the images of each character.

```
info face="FontName" size=78 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=0 stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0 spacing=0,0
common lineHeight=93 base=73 scaleW=512 scaleH=512 pages=1 packed=0
page id=0 file="fontsheet.png"
chars count=83
char id=32   x=0     y=0     width=0     height=0     xoffset=0     yoffset=73    xadvance=25     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=36   x=0     y=0     width=46     height=83     xoffset=1     yoffset=0    xadvance=51     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=106   x=46     y=0     width=19     height=82     xoffset=2     yoffset=9    xadvance=26     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=41   x=65     y=0     width=20     height=75     xoffset=1     yoffset=3    xadvance=26     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=40   x=85     y=0     width=21     height=75     xoffset=2     yoffset=3    xadvance=27     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=96   x=106     y=0     width=31     height=75     xoffset=5     yoffset=0    xadvance=39     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=64   x=137     y=0     width=72     height=68     xoffset=1     yoffset=7    xadvance=77     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=48   x=209     y=0     width=51     height=68     xoffset=1     yoffset=7    xadvance=57     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=85   x=260     y=0     width=54     height=68     xoffset=1     yoffset=7    xadvance=60     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=79   x=314     y=0     width=60     height=68     xoffset=1     yoffset=7    xadvance=65     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=38   x=374     y=0     width=60     height=67     xoffset=2     yoffset=8    xadvance=65     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=54   x=434     y=0     width=47     height=67     xoffset=1     yoffset=8    xadvance=53     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=121   x=0     y=83     width=43     height=67     xoffset=1     yoffset=26    xadvance=48     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=113   x=43     y=83     width=48     height=67     xoffset=1     yoffset=24    xadvance=53     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=112   x=91     y=83     width=48     height=67     xoffset=0        
// etc...
```

Comment: I did something similar using perl, a script that reads the  image size and outputs an xml. Didn't take long, a few minutes of fiddling.

Comment: @Majte I already have a xml file. I need a .fnt file that maps each character to the specific location on the screen.

Comment: But I need to specify xoffset for each image/character I parse. It basically means to roll my own UI app for this. But how do people normally get images to work as fonts? I mean exporting a `.ttf` to a `.fnt` is greta but .ttf is just black or white so there is no change in creating anything slightly cool looking or fitting the game art.

Comment: Creating an app like this will take "a lot" of time. But the thing is, I have the feeling I am reinventing the wheel since any "artistic" font in a game needs to have the same treatment as I need.

Comment: This seems to be a part to your answer. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74010/how-do-you-create-fnt-angelcode-format-files-from-existing-bitmaps

Comment: @Majte but I want to specify `xadvance` for each character otherwise it is monospaced.

Comment: So...you have xml and a image file for each character and you want to parse the xml file, convert it to plain .txt and pack the image files into a single one?

Comment: I understand. How good are your coding skills and which platform are you using for your gamedev?

Comment: I have to produce a code over the weekend for my game to have correct spacing, when reading from a bitmap font. If you hang on a few days and no answer is given on here I'll post my code for you. However it will be C++.

Comment: I have VS for c++ ;) just hate the syntax itself but I can handle it. I guess I have to create my own tool for this. Where someone can pick an image and link it to a ascii character and set the spacing of it. But this will take me way more then a couple of hours to do properly.